# Team Foundation Server 2012 supporting issue on SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have upgraded SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2017 Standard Edition. Team Foundation Server 2012 is now using with SQL Server 2017.

After upgrading to SQL Server 2017, Team Foundation Server 2012 is working fine except creation of new project Collections.

Please help me as I am stuck badly.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Click to view Error image]

Comment: You don't. [TFS 2012 supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/requirements) running against SQL Server versions 2008R2 and 2012. The only version of TFS that is supported running against SQL Server 2017 is TFS 2018.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/requirements#sql-server SQL Server 2017 works with TFS 2018 only. This is why testing, and dependency checks, are so important before upgrading. You'll either need to upgrade your TFS, or go back to SQL Server 2012 until you can upgrade both TFS and SQL Server.

Comment: And note that if you're rolling back (as Larnu suggests as an option), you'll be doing that from *backups* of your databases that were created whilst it was a 2012 server. A 2012 server can process neither backups nor database files from a 2017 server.

Comment: Indeed. if you only have a old backup of the 2012 database, you may have to re-key all the information/changes that have been made since using your 2017 instance. if you no longer have a 2012 backup, and can't update your TFS version, I'm afraid you've gone past the point of no return now.

Comment: Is there any way out that I can down grade my **sql server 2012** database which has updated to **sql server 2017**. Then I can reconfigure my **TFS 2012** with **SQL Server 2012**. Please help me on the same.

Comment: Nope. Upgrading a database is a one way process.

Comment: Could it help to change the database compatilbility level? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017 SQL 2017 supports level 110 which belongs to SQL 2012. But I have no clue if that would help in a case like this.

Comment: @PeterB - that might "work" (i.e. eliminate the current error) but since it's an unsupported configuration, if it turned around tomorrow and starting corrupting all of their data, they'd have no recourse if they went to MS for support.

Comment: I stuck badly. No options are left in my hand. Either I have to configure TFS 2012 to support SQL Server 2017 or I can downgrade from SQL Server 2017 to SQL Server 2012. Upgrade to TFS 2018 is not possible for me right now. I can do almost all activities (Create sub collections, Checked In/Out) rather than creating new Collections in TFS 2012 on SQL Server 2017. Please look into the matter.

Comment: All of the above comments still hold. I'm not sure what you're expecting anyone else to be able to do.

Comment: Like above, no one can change that TFS 2012 won't work on SQL Server apart from Microsoft, and I very much doubt that is going to change, ever. Like I said before, this is why testing needs to be done before an upgrade and you need to check compatibility of products. I hate to say it, but it's clear you didn't take those steps and now you're in the position you are in. Still the 2 comments with a solution remain: go back to 2012 (and likely lose any data you changed in 2017) or upgrade to TFS 2018. Those are your **only** options at this stage. Nothing can change that now.